# Requiring sequilize modules returns undefined in some express app files

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, sequelize.js

**Goal** - creating middleware-like callback in userHandler in util.js util.js for some express routes in express app, generated with express-generator and sequlize-cli.

**Expected** - user model successfully used in routes and userHandler in util.js.

**Result** - user model successfully works in login route, but is undefined in userHandler in util.js. When requiring models fully getting {}. Require seems correct.

**console error**

```
[nodemon] starting `node ./bin/www`
{}
Fri, 15 Jan 2021 14:54:42 GMT server:server Listening on port 8000
here
Fri, 15 Jan 2021 15:53:33 GMT server:server TypeError: Cannot read property 'findByPk' of undefined
    at C:\Users\bpali\Desktop\authorization1\server\utils.js:40:27
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
    at async C:\Users\bpali\Desktop\authorization1\server\utils.js:12:5
GET /users/my-info 500 23.306 ms - 2
```

**File structure**

[image: File structure]

**util.js**

```
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
var debug = require('debug')('server:server');
const secret = process.env.SECRET || SgxLbntQGfukf1yEAYZyzLBJKvop8Z2k6q1YG0wOHXZMgbVNhhsLaSIOB8Rkw9Pe4anRpTAE8h95RCwDYLjSsbJhpdZruVKzpzGgw1bnqCLLS1gAU1R1uChtRYDkSBOoZkFdnG3sRVLtJz63gqEQkq7owtaACYOXAd1fPOFkUgwgxammROY1NgpmUJR9YOwhVtcq5mTu;
const { User } = require('./models');
const models = require('./models');
console.log(models); // {} - ???

const verifyToken = async (token) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => jwt.verify(token, secret, (err, decoded) => err ? reject(err) : resolve(decoded)));
const signToken = async (payload, options = { expiresIn: '365d' }) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => jwt.sign(payload, secret, options, (err, token) => err ? reject(err) : resolve(token)));
const asyncErrorHandler = (asyncFn, ...args) => async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    await asyncFn(req, res, next, ...args);
    next();
  } catch (e) {
    debug(e);
    res.status(500).send(e);
  }
}
const userHandler = (allowedTypes) => asyncErrorHandler(async (req, res, next) => {
  const autHeader = req.get('Authorization');
  if (!autHeader) {
    res.status(401).send('Unauthorized');
    next('route');
  }
  const autSplit = autHeader.split && autHeader.split(' ');
  if (!autSplit || autSplit.length !== 2 || !(autSplit[0] === 'Token' || autSplit[0] === 'Bearer')) {
    res.status(401).send('Wrong format of authorisation');
    next('route');
  }
  const token = autSplit[1];
  console.log('here');
  let decodedToken;
  try {
    decodedToken = await verifyToken(token);
  } catch (e) {
    res.status(403).send(`Wrong token! ${e.name + ': ' + e.message}`);
    next('route');
  }
  const { login } = decodedToken;
  const user = await User.findByPk(login);
  if (!user) {
    res.status(403).send('Wrong user');
    next('route');
  }
  req.user = user;
  if (allowedTypes && allowedTypes.indexOf && allowedTypes.indexOf(user.role) === -1) {
    res.status(403).send('Not allowed role');
    next('route');
  }  
  next();
});

module.exports = { verifyToken, signToken, asyncErrorHandler, userHandler }
```

**routes/users.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
const { QueryTypes } = require('sequelize');
const { User, sequelize } = require('../models');
const { asyncErrorHandler, userHandler } = require('../utils');

/* GET users listing. */
// router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
//   res.send('respond with a resource');
// });

router.post('/login', asyncErrorHandler(async function (req, res, next) {
  const { login, password } = req.body;
  if (!login || !password || typeof login !== 'string' || typeof password !== 'string'){
    res.status(400).send('Not empty login and password strings needed in json body');
    next();
  }
  const user = await User.findByPk(login);
  if (!user){
    res.status(400).send('Absent login');
    next('route');
  }
  if (!(await user.checkPassword(password))){
    res.status(400).send('Wrong password');
    next('route');
  };
  const { type } = user
  res.json({
    token: await user.makeToken(),
    user: { login, type },
  });
  // next();
}));

router.post('/register', asyncErrorHandler(async function (req, res, next) {
  const { login, password } = req.body;
  if (!login || !password || typeof login !== 'string' || typeof password !== 'string'){
    res.status(400).send('Not empty login and password strings needed in json body');
    next('route');
  }
  if (await User.findByPk(login)) {
    res.status(403).send('Busy login');
    next('route');
  }
  const user = User.build({ login, type: 'user' });
  await user.setPassword(password);
  await user.save();
  const { type } = user
  res.json({ login, type });
  // next();
}));

router.get('/my-info', userHandler(), function (req, res, next) {
  const { login, type } = req.user;
  res.json({ login, type });
});

router.get('/user-info/:login', userHandler(['admin']), asyncErrorHandler(async function (req, res, next) {
  const user = await (User.findByPk(req.params.login));
  if (!user) {
    res.status(404).send('Login not found');
    next('route');
  }
  const { login, type } = user;
  req.json({ login, type });
  // next();
}));

router.get('/list-users', userHandler(['admin']), asyncErrorHandler(async function (req, res, next) {
  const users = await sequelize.query("SELECT * FROM `users`", { type: QueryTypes.SELECT });
  console.log(users);
  res.json(users);
}));

module.exports = router;
```

**models/index.js**

```
'use strict';

const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
const basename = path.basename(__filename);
const env = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development';
const config = require(__dirname + '/../config/config.json')[env];
const db = {};

let sequelize;
if (config.use_env_variable) {
  sequelize = new Sequelize(process.env[config.use_env_variable], config);
} else {
  sequelize = new Sequelize(config.database, config.username, config.password, config);
}

fs
  .readdirSync(__dirname)
  .filter(file => {
    return (file.indexOf('.') !== 0) && (file !== basename) && (file.slice(-3) === '.js');
  })
  .forEach(file => {
    const model = require(path.join(__dirname, file))(sequelize, Sequelize.DataTypes);
    db[model.name] = model;
  });

Object.keys(db).forEach(modelName => {
  if (db[modelName].associate) {
    db[modelName].associate(db);
  }
});

db.sequelize = sequelize;
db.Sequelize = Sequelize;

module.exports = db;
```

**models/user.js**

```
'use strict';
const {
  Model
} = require('sequelize');
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt');
const { signToken } = require('../utils');

module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  class User extends Model {
    /**
     * Helper method for defining associations.
     * This method is not a part of Sequelize lifecycle.
     * The `models/index` file will call this method automatically.
     */
    static associate(models) {
      // define association here
    }
    async setPassword (password) {
      this.password = await bcrypt.hash(password, 10);
    }
    async checkPassword (password) {
      return await bcrypt.compare(password, this.password);
    }
    async makeToken() {
      const { login } = this;
      return await signToken({ login });
    }
  };
  User.init({
    login: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      primaryKey: true,
      allowNull: false,
    },
    password: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
    },
    type: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
    },
  }, {
    sequelize,
    modelName: 'User',
  });
  return User;
};
```

**app.js**

```
var createError = require('http-errors');
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var logger = require('morgan');

var indexRouter = require('./routes/index');
var usersRouter = require('./routes/users');

var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'hbs');

app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/', indexRouter);
app.use('/users', usersRouter);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  next(createError(404));
});

// error handler
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  // set locals, only providing error in development
  res.locals.message = err.message;
  res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

  // render the error page
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error');
});

module.exports = app;
```

**bin/www**

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
require('dotenv').config()
/**
 * Module dependencies.
 */

var app = require('../app');
var debug = require('debug')('server:server');
var http = require('http');

/**
 * Get port from environment and store in Express.
 */

var port = normalizePort(process.env.PORT || '3000');
app.set('port', port);

/**
 * Create HTTP server.
 */

var server = http.createServer(app);

/**
 * Listen on provided port, on all network interfaces.
 */

server.listen(port);
server.on('error', onError);
server.on('listening', onListening);

/**
 * Normalize a port into a number, string, or false.
 */

function normalizePort(val) {
  var port = parseInt(val, 10);

  if (isNaN(port)) {
    // named pipe
    return val;
  }

  if (port >= 0) {
    // port number
    return port;
  }

  return false;
}

/**
 * Event listener for HTTP server "error" event.
 */

function onError(error) {
  if (error.syscall !== 'listen') {
    throw error;
  }

  var bind = typeof port === 'string'
    ? 'Pipe ' + port
    : 'Port ' + port;

  // handle specific listen errors with friendly messages
  switch (error.code) {
    case 'EACCES':
      console.error(bind + ' requires elevated privileges');
      process.exit(1);
      break;
    case 'EADDRINUSE':
      console.error(bind + ' is already in use');
      process.exit(1);
      break;
    default:
      throw error;
  }
}

/**
 * Event listener for HTTP server "listening" event.
 */

function onListening() {
  var addr = server.address();
  var bind = typeof addr === 'string'
    ? 'pipe ' + addr
    : 'port ' + addr.port;
  debug('Listening on ' + bind);
}
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "server",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node ./bin/www",
    "dev": "nodemon ./bin/www"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "bcrypt": "^5.0.0",
    "cookie-parser": "~1.4.4",
    "debug": "~2.6.9",
    "dotenv": "^8.2.0",
    "express": "~4.16.1",
    "hbs": "~4.0.4",
    "http-errors": "~1.6.3",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
    "morgan": "~1.9.1",
    "pg": "^8.5.1",
    "pg-hstore": "^2.3.3",
    "sequelize": "^6.3.5"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "nodemon": "^2.0.7"
  }
}
```

**.env**

```
DEBUG=server:*
PORT=8000
SECRET=SgxLbntQGfukf1yEAYZyzLBJKvop8Z2k6q1YG0wOHXZMgbVNhhsLaSIOB8Rkw9Pe4anRpTAE8h95RCwDYLjSsbJhpdZruVKzpzGgw1bnqCLLS1gAU1R1uChtRYDkSBOoZkFdnG3sRVLtJz63gqEQkq7owtaACYOXAd1fPOFkUgwgxammROY1NgpmUJR9YOwhVtcq5mTu
```

Comment: In the models/user.js file, would it help to define the User class outside of the function being exported?  In other words, defining the User class above the line that says "module.exports = function (sequelize, DataTypes) => {"?  It might help.  You're getting an error that seems to indicate the User model is undefined...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Problem found** - unclear circular dependency

**utils.js** requires **models/index.js**

**models/index.js** not directly requires **models/user.js**

**models/user.js** requires **utils.js**, more exactly - **signToken** function from it

**What was done** - renamed **utils.js** in **routeUtils.js**, put **signToken** and **verifyToken** functions to new file **tokenUtils.js**, updated imports in other files, so this circular dependency will not happen, after this, it imported correctly.

Main updates:

**File structure**

[image: File structure]

**routeUtils.js**

```
// const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
var debug = require('debug')('server:server');
// const secret = process.env.SECRET || SgxLbntQGfukf1yEAYZyzLBJKvop8Z2k6q1YG0wOHXZMgbVNhhsLaSIOB8Rkw9Pe4anRpTAE8h95RCwDYLjSsbJhpdZruVKzpzGgw1bnqCLLS1gAU1R1uChtRYDkSBOoZkFdnG3sRVLtJz63gqEQkq7owtaACYOXAd1fPOFkUgwgxammROY1NgpmUJR9YOwhVtcq5mTu;
const { User } = require('./models');
const { verifyToken } = require('./tokenUtils');
// const models = require('./models');
// console.log(models); // {} - ???

// const verifyToken = async (token) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => jwt.verify(token, secret, (err, decoded) => err ? reject(err) : resolve(decoded)));
// const signToken = async (payload, options = { expiresIn: '365d' }) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => jwt.sign(payload, secret, options, (err, token) => err ? reject(err) : resolve(token)));
const asyncErrorHandler = (asyncFn, ...args) => async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    await asyncFn(req, res, next, ...args);
    // next();
  } catch (e) {
    debug(e);
    res.status(500).send(e);
  }
}
const userHandler = (allowedTypes) => asyncErrorHandler(async (req, res, next) => {
  const autHeader = req.get('Authorization');
  if (!autHeader) {
    res.status(401).send('Unauthorized');
    next('route');
  }
  const autSplit = autHeader.split && autHeader.split(' ');
  if (!autSplit || autSplit.length !== 2 || !(autSplit[0] === 'Token' || autSplit[0] === 'Bearer')) {
    res.status(401).send('Wrong format of authorisation');
    next('route');
  }
  const token = autSplit[1];
  // console.log('here');
  let decodedToken;
  try {
    decodedToken = await verifyToken(token);
  } catch (e) {
    debug(e);
    res.status(403).send(`Wrong token! ${e.name + ': ' + e.message}`);
    next('route');
  }
  const { login } = decodedToken;
  const user = await User.findByPk(login);
  if (!user) {
    res.status(403).send('Wrong user');
    next('route');
  }
  req.user = user;
  if (allowedTypes && allowedTypes.indexOf && allowedTypes.indexOf(user.type) === -1) {
    // console.log('here');
    res.status(403).send('Not allowed user type');
    next('route');
  }
  next();
});

module.exports = { /* verifyToken, signToken, */ asyncErrorHandler, userHandler }
```

**tokenUtils.js**

```
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
const secret = process.env.SECRET || SgxLbntQGfukf1yEAYZyzLBJKvop8Z2k6q1YG0wOHXZMgbVNhhsLaSIOB8Rkw9Pe4anRpTAE8h95RCwDYLjSsbJhpdZruVKzpzGgw1bnqCLLS1gAU1R1uChtRYDkSBOoZkFdnG3sRVLtJz63gqEQkq7owtaACYOXAd1fPOFkUgwgxammROY1NgpmUJR9YOwhVtcq5mTu;

const verifyToken = async (token) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => jwt.verify(token, secret, (err, decoded) => err ? reject(err) : resolve(decoded)));
const signToken = async (payload, options = { expiresIn: '365d' }) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => jwt.sign(payload, secret, options, (err, token) => err ? reject(err) : resolve(token)));

module.exports = { verifyToken, signToken };
```

**models/user.js**

```
'use strict';
const {
  Model
} = require('sequelize');
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt');
const { signToken } = require('../tokenUtils');

module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  class User extends Model {
    /**
     * Helper method for defining associations.
     * This method is not a part of Sequelize lifecycle.
     * The `models/index` file will call this method automatically.
     */
    static associate(models) {
      // define association here
    }
    async setPassword (password) {
      this.password = await bcrypt.hash(password, 10);
    }
    async checkPassword (password) {
      return await bcrypt.compare(password, this.password);
    }
    async makeToken() {
      const { login } = this;
      return await signToken({ login });
    }
  };
  User.init({
    login: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      primaryKey: true,
      allowNull: false,
    },
    password: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
    },
    type: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
    },
  }, {
    sequelize,
    modelName: 'User',
  });
  return User;
};
```